# Weird shader behavior on different devices

Tags: libgdx, android, shaders, glsl, fragment-shader

I'm trying to combine an ordinary shader with a Single Distance Field shader (for fonts and scalable icons) into one shader program. 
The idea is simple - if uv.x is less than 1.0, it is drawn as usual, and if more than 1.0 then SDF is used (using GL_REPEAT uv.x and uv.x + 1.0 look similar)

Fragment shader code:

```
precision mediump float;
precision mediump int;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform float u_smoothing;

void main() {
  // SDF
  float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).a;
  float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - u_smoothing, 0.5 + u_smoothing, distance);
  vec4 sdfColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha * v_color.a);

  // Regular
  vec4 regularColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);

  // Making a choice
  gl_FragColor = mix(regularColor, sdfColor, step(1.0, v_texCoords.x));
}
```

It works and looks fine on desktop and most of popular Android devices but not on Oneplus One, Xiaomi Redmi 4A and Moto G devices. 
This is how it must look like and how it actually looks on desktops and many other devices (Samsung S8, Xiaomi 3s, Pixel 2 etc.):
[image: Normaly rendered]

And this is how it looks like on Moto G, Oneplus One & some others:
[image]

I tried to find a problematic function, but without success.
First I tried to use the usual condition instead of mix():

```
void main() {
  // ...

  // Making a choice
  // gl_FragColor = mix(regularColor, sdfColor, step(1.0, v_texCoords.x));
  if (v_texCoords.x < 1.0) {
    gl_FragColor = regularColor;
  } else {
    gl_FragColor = sdfColor;
  }
}
```

Nothing has changed - this shader works well on most devices and is still bad on some others. 
I decided that the problem lies in the calculation of sdfColor and changed fragment shader code a bit to check:

```
void main() {
  // ...

  // Making a choice
  gl_FragColor = sdfColor;  // Always using SDF
}
```

But this shader worked equally on all devices, which indicates that sdfColor is calculated correctly. This next screenshot was taken on Moto G:
[image]

Then I tried to differentiate the regions of textures with different colors:

```
void main() {
  // ...

  // Making a choice
  if (v_texCoords.x < 1.0) {
    gl_FragColor = regularColor;
    gl_FragColor.r = 1.0;  // Full red channel for regular texture regions without SDF (UV.x < 1.0)
  } else {
    gl_FragColor = sdfColor;
    gl_FragColor.r = 0.0;  // No red channel for SDF 
  }
}
```

On Moto G and other devices it looks as expected: 
[image]

It seems to me that using mix() or conditions implicitly changes something else.

**Update 1:**

Using different precision qualifier (highp / lowp) or completely removing it didn't help and made no visual changes.

This bug starts to appear on desktop (OpenGL) if I add `#version 100`. Changing it to `#version 110` or higher returns normal rendering.

When `#version 100` is used on Android (OpenGL ES 2.0) it renders as if there were no `#version` qualifier at all (exactly the same as described in my question - on Nexus 5x it looks good, on Moto G it doesn't).

Using `#version 300 es` on Android (OpenGL ES 3.0, looks like it is supported Moto G 3rd) with respective changes to the code (uniform, varying, texture2D replaced by in, out, texture) doesn't fix the problem (good on Nexus, bad on Moto).

Precision qualifier was not used in both cases. Looks like `#version` does no effect to this problem on Android but makes it appear on desktop when set to 100 (is it OpenGL 1.0?...)

**Update 2:**

Writing `v_texCoords.x` to the separate `float` and using it in `mix()` fixes this bug but only for desktop when `#version 100` is also used:

```
#version 100
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
uniform float u_smoothing;

void main() {
  float x = v_texCoords.x; // Writing to the separate float

  // SDF
  float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).a;
  float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - u_smoothing, 0.5 + u_smoothing, distance);
  vec4 sdfColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha * v_color.a);

  // Regular
  vec4 regularColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);

  // Making a choice
  gl_FragColor = mix(regularColor, sdfColor, step(1.0, x)); // Using x instead of v_texCoords.x
}
```

It doesn't fix the problem on Moto G. Also when I move `float x = v_texCoords.x;` to the line right before `gl_FragColor = ...` the problem remains on desktop:

```
void main() {
  // SDF
  float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).a;
  float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - u_smoothing, 0.5 + u_smoothing, distance);
  vec4 sdfColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha * v_color.a);

  // Regular
  vec4 regularColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords);

  // Making a choice
  float x = v_texCoords.x; // Writing to the separate float, this time it doesn't fix the bug
  gl_FragColor = mix(regularColor, sdfColor, step(1.0, x)); // Using x instead of v_texCoords.x
}
```

Comment: I always calculated sdfColor in the same way. I did not replace it with anything else because it seemed to me that sdfColor is calculated correctly (when I used only sdfColor it worked well)

Comment: No, replacing mix() with condition doesn't fix the problem, it behaves exactly as with mix()

Comment: Oops, my bad, I have been misunderstanding the problem, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Do you actually have all those devices how did you manage to test this?  Also you might want to try vulkan and see if you get the same issues. The shader wouldn't have to change, but the driver will be consuming SPIR-V instead of the actual shader code text, so its possible that there are driver implementation differences for EGL on those devices that cause this issue, if it worked the same everywhere on vulkan it would hint a problem with the implementation of EGL on those devices, or you are using undefined behavior.

Comment: also try using `highp` instead of `mediump`, or [get rid of the precision qualifiers as recommended](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Precision_qualifiers) for more modern versions of OpenGL ES.  Try `lowp` and see if you see any noticable difference as well and try doing the same for int.   Maybe try making the code even simpler for the compiler by always assigning first before using members, its possible the GLSL compiler is bugged on those systems.   Also you should probably specify the GLSL version with `#version`.

Comment: I tried to change precisions, it was my first thought, but they didn't change anything. Thanks for the tips, I'll try them and see if they will change anything.

Comment: I have tried to add #version and to change precision, added an update to the end of the question. Still can't fix the problem but found the way to make it appear on desktop. Could you give me a hint of how to assign first before using members?

Comment: Added second update - now I found how to fix the bug that I triggered on desktop but it doesn't fix the bug on Moto G. The very moment when fixing a bug makes it only worse - now I can't reproduce it on desktop, which would be very handy.

Comment: Anything wrong with the target resolution you are setting? Looks like the resolution that's being rendered is very low.

Comment: @Ayyappa yes indeed, looks like it is rendered in lower resolution. But I did not change anything related to it and even don't know how is it possible to set multiple resolutions for one batch of vertices (regular (uv.x < 1) and sdf (uv.y) vertices are passed in one batch)

Comment: @therainycat wait... what are you doing to make texture2D only have alpha channel, I suspect that is what is screwing up...  that is code that is outside of GLSL... also FWI, I only get notified of replies if you @ symbol me.

Comment: @therainycat You also use `distance` which is a reserved word that may not be respected by some compilers, but will for others...

Comment: @therainycat try this code (but make sure I didn't break anything first) https://pastebin.com/sBLUXZDn,  uses opengl es 300, instead of varying uses `in` so you'll have to change the vertex shader to using `out` instead of attribute.  Opengl es 3 glsl doesnot support attribute and varying.

Comment: @snb texture2D is just a regular white texture region with alpha, I do not modify it in any way in code outside of GLSL. I'm not sure it is something out of GLSL causes this problem because when sdfColor is returned (without mix() / condition) it looks good. I tried your code and it works exactly as my first version of fragment shader (good on desktop & nexus 5x, bugged on Moto G 3rd gen), I did some minor tweaks to it though (300 -> 300 es, texture2d -> texture, out fragColor): https://pastebin.com/EiapbuAz

Comment: @therainycat I was mistaken about the texture, I hadn't read the entire code at that point. Ok that is very weird...  what does only doing sdf do with this version, and then what does doing the branching with out stepping do with this version, and post both code on pastebin, try adding one layer of indirection before assigning to `gl_fragcolor` too, see if that does anything, then try differentiating color with still only using sdfcolor.  You might also try making a webgl application and seeing if the same thing happens on motog...  I'm as confused as you are as to why this isn't working...

Comment: @snb thanks for your suggestions and help. Unfortunately I need to work on other things and this issue took too much time. I just felt back to regular textures till the time I find a solution or at least have some spare time

Comment: @therainycat there may be a way to submit a bug report to moto or something, I feel like this is likely something dumb along those lines, as I can't see how you've written invalid OpenGL (except with distance and using varying instead of  in/out on 300 es)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but for whatever reason, you're getting major precision loss in your texture coordinates (on some platforms). You can tell this is the problem because the blockiness isn't isotropic: Your textures actually still have their full resolution in the Y direction, they're only getting chunked up in the X direction.

One way you can further tell if/that this is the problem is that if you change your SDF condition to 2.0, and adjust your code to match, the problem should become twice as bad.

Given that your test with just sdfColor was OK (I assume that was still with UV.x > 1.0), I feel like this is probably the GLSL compiler doing some bad floating-point optimizations on you. The part where storing the number to a separate float helped for desktop OpenGL but not your other platforms adds weight to that.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason the texel values are different ( > 1.0) on the other platforms. Are they using high-res screens? The pixel depth might be double (e.g. check for uv.x > 2.0) Might need to write a separate shader for those devices.

Comment: Why do you think the texel values are different?

Comment: try it out and see. Clearly the shader never reaches the ( > 1.0) branch

Comment: uv.x is set to >1.0 by me in the code outside of GLSL to mark texture regions that must be drawn with SDF. It is a part of vertex data passed to the shader and it is same for every platform. What are you suggesting to try?